# Authenticate user if present in the group

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators, django-authentication

I want to authenticate user only if the user in present in a specific group. Can someone tell me how can I do it please !

I am doing this to add user to a group when user signs up but it is showing me an error **( AttributeError at /stusignup/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' )**

```
 def stusignup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       name = request.POST['name']
       email = request.POST['email']
       pass1 = request.POST['password1']
       pass2 = request.POST['password2']

       if not pass1 == pass2:
           messages.error(request,"Please enter same password!")
       else:
           myuser = 
           User.objects.create_user(username=name,password=pass1,email=email)
        
    
           myuser.name = name
           myuser.email = email
           myuser.password = pass1
           stuser = myuser.save()

           group = Group.objects.get(name='Student')
           stuser.groups.add(group)

           return redirect('studentloginpage')

return render(request,'stusignup.html')
```

views.py **(I tried this but even if the user is present in the group it is going to the else part{ return httpresponse..... } )**

```
 def stuloginpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    user_email = request.POST['email']
    pass1 = request.POST['password']
    user = User.objects.get(email=user_email,password=pass1)

    if user.groups.filter(name = 'Student').exists():
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('homepage')
            #messages.success(request,'Login Succcessful')

        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username OR Password is INCORRECT")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You aren't a Student !")
```

I also tried this

```
 def is_student(user):
   return user.groups.filter(name='Student')  

 @user_passes_test(is_student)
```

***I need help in adding the user to a group at the time of sign up and then before login checking if the user is in a particular group !***

Comment: what do you mean by "not working", please make it clear.

Comment: `save()` doesn't return the model. You need to change `stuser.groups.add(group)` to `myuser.groups.add(group)`.